# mod_rewrite to encode the url after the?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string, querystringparameter

I want to tranform all the content of the URL after the ? to be encoded

example if I write this URL in the browser:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/?page=exams/product/vmware/
```

to be transformed to

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/?page=exams%2Fproduct%2Fvmware%2F
```

this is because Google index the above page as

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/product/vmware/
```

which does not exist

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This where I have gotten to, I can replace / with % BUT not %2F because RewriteRule reads %2 as a regex group. And then even if I can replace / with %2F modrewrite will probably read it as a / then creating an infinite loop.

In my testing with the code I have so far

localhost:81/?page=exams/product/vmware/

becomes

localhost:81/?page=exams%25product%25vmware%25

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)\/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1%%2 [N,E=redirect:true]
RewriteCond %{ENV:redirect} ^true$
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [R]
</IfModule>
```

---

I don't know how to (or if this can be done) with modrewrite BUT here is javascript client side way of doing this

```
<script>
    var p = window.location.pathname;
    var q = window.location.search;

    history.pushState('data', 'title', p+"/?"+encodeURIComponent(q.substr(1)));
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I am looking for a solution for the full website and not to update page by page

Comment: Ok. I will take a look at modrewrite to see what can be done there.

Comment: What technology is the website built on?

Comment: the Server is Apache, is a custom CMS made on PHP

Comment: See updated answer, maybe you can go further while I try to complete this.

Comment: Also, javascript can be applied to entire website by placing it in the footer. The CMS is written in PHP, so maybe also consider a PHP solution within the CMS.